# Should the add-on allways be the same amount of money than the rebuy?

Tags: rules, tournament

In a tournament with rebuy and add-on, should the players pay the same amount of cash for the add-on than for the rebuy?

Is there any rule about it?

Comment: Just a thought about add-ons, unrelated to your question. Almost everyone who I have heard of getting busted for stealing tournament money has done it by stealing the add-ons. they are really hard to document and easy to steal. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's typically up to the cardroom or casino as to the price and amount of chips you can get. Most places I've seen that have offered both rebuys and addons have had a starting stack add-on, although I have seen it lower than starting stack too.

I think it probably depends on how much the add-on and rebuy are giving. If it's the same amount of chips for the same amount of cash, yeah probably should pay the same amount. However if they're giving say 5k chips as an add-on for x amount, but then a rebuy is say 10k chips also for x then obviously those chips are inflated on the add-on. In that case probably avoid paying the same price if you're getting less.

One other thing I've seen some places do, the rebuy and initial buy-in are raked, but I've seen the add-on not be raked in some places. Things like say 100$ tournament, rake is like 10$ for example, the add-on was only 90$. However most rake all both buyins, rebuys and add-ons.

Long story short, I don't believe there is any rules about this from the casino/cardroom side. They get to set the price of admission to their games. In terms of as a player, I'd say the only rule should be don't pay an inflated price for the chips like I mentioned above.